# How to find files that don't have a matching spec file

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I am wondering if this can be done in the terminal or any simple programs.

In my project folder, i have files like:

```
my-component.ts
my-component.spec.ts

my-component-without-spec.ts
```

Most component files will have a matching spec file.  But some don't.  I want to find the ones that don't have matching spec file.

In Mac OS, I tried:

```
find -E . -regex '.+(?<!spec\.ts)'
```

I got:

```
find: -regex: .+(?<!spec\.ts): repetition-operator operand invalid
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PCRE regex with `find`. The `(?<!spec\.ts)` negative lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded by `spec.ts`, and you mist probably wanted to just match all files ending with `.ts` but not ending with `spec.ts`.

So you can use

```sh
find . -iname '*spec.ts' -not -iname '*.spec.ts'
```

Here,

- `-iname '*spec.ts'` - searches for all files ending with `spec.ts` (case insensitive)
- `-not -iname '*.spec.ts'` - and NOT ending with `.spec.ts` (case insensitive).

Comment: that doesn't work. it finds `my-component.ts` as in my example.  but i want to find `my-component-without-spec.ts` only

Comment: @techguy2000 You did not specify the exact output you want, and all the description led me to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is a simple program running under macOS that prints all .ts files without an associated spec file.

Obviously there are many possibilities, one would be a simple Python3 script:

- collects all .ts files recursively in a given directory with `glob.glob`.
- for each file not ending in spec.ts, construct the corresponding spec filename
- if this spec file is not in the collection, it will be output as missing

Code-wise, this could then look like this:

```
import glob
import os.path
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def find_unmatched(root_dir):
    all_ts_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*.ts'), recursive=True)
    for ts_file in all_ts_files:
        if not ts_file.endswith('.spec.ts'):
            p = Path(ts_file)
            folder = os.path.split(ts_file)[0]
            corresponding_spec = os.path.join(folder, (p.stem + '.spec' + p.suffix))
            if corresponding_spec not in all_ts_files:
                print(f"missing: {corresponding_spec}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("usage: find_unmatched <dir>")
    else:
        find_unmatched(sys.argv[1])
```

Notes: The code was written for readability rather than performance, but should not be a problem for this use case. Above script works with Python 3.8.2 installed e.g. with XCode command line tools.

You would call it like this:

```
python3 find_unmatched.py .
```

For the given example case, the output would look like this:

```
missing: my-component-without-spec.spec.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting 2 solutions:

#### 1. Filter `find` command results

```
  find . -name "*.ts" |grep -v "\.spec\.ts"
```

#### 2. Use `-not` option in `find` command

```
  find . -name "*.ts" -not -name "*.spec.ts"
```